# Changing the curser into a custom one

Tags: c#, uwp, cursor

I have found about the coreccursor.custom property but I could not figure out how to set a value to it

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Answer (score 0):

To start with the simplest (maybe it's enough), you can set up one of the predefined cursors, by picking one of the available options:

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerCursor = 
     new Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursor(Windows.UI.Core.CoreCursorType.Hand, 0);
```

`.Hand` is one of the several available.

For a very own custom cursor, you'd have to do a little more.
Check these references: 
[one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b30ba58-3552-4bf9-9346-991c81e47416/uwpcustom-cursor-in-uwp?forum=wpdevelop) and [two](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devfish/2012/08/01/customcursors-in-windows-8-csharp-metro-applications/).